# Visual Studio not loading symbol and showing error: . Cannot find or open the PDB file. Even though the PDB is present in the symbol server

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, symbols, pdb-files

I have a private symbol server where symbols are located. I have symbol file **test.pdb** and corresponding dll **test.dll.** The symbol file should match. The location where symbol file is located is in a folder say AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. When I run a third party library that indexes symbols it correctly creates AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA and places test.pdb inside it. But VS 2015 is not able to find and load this symbol. It is giving error "Cannot find or open the PDB file"

In forder to verify that the third party library created the correct folder and indexed symbols correctly I verified the folder name by indexing with Windows provided symstore.exe, the same folder AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA is created and the test.pdb is inside it. Somehow Visual Studio is able to load symbols from here.

Could some one suggest what must be going wrong? All other symbols indexed via third party library is correctly found by VS 2015. This is one of the symbol which is not.

Comment: Maybe this pdb is created with a newer version and VS2015 does not know how to open it.
Windbg has a symbols loading logging feature that will show the paths and results of symbols loading trys. Try it, maybe it will give you some hints. I'm not aware if VS has same feature.
Open your exe in windbg (`File->Open executable...`), activate symbols search logging by running `!sym noisy`, run `.reload /f` to load all symbols. Windbg loads all symbols and logs all loading events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart VS and it was able to locate the symbols on its own.